# Comparing two text files and the matches go to a new file

Tags: python, data-structures, compare

In python I would like to find a way to compare two text files and read one line by line and find it's match if any in the other file. If they match I would like to take that string and write it to a new file.

I do not know how I would even start this the only thing I know how to do is how to read a text file but not compare it to another.

Any starting tips, links, or ideas would be great.

Thank you

Comment: How large are these files?

Comment: Its two text fiules about 6-7 thousands lines each hence why I'd like to automate this

Comment: This is really small, so just `common_lines = set(file1.readlines()) & set(file2.readlines())` should be sufficient (where `file1` and `file2` are objects returned from `open()`). It is far from memory-efficient solution, though.

Comment: I don't have samples, what I have is two text files and on each line is a string, I would like to read a string in File 1 and search for it in file 2, if there is a match just copy that string into a third file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
     with open('file2.txt') as file2:
           newfile = open('newfile.txt','w')
           for range(len(file1.readlines())):
                s1 = file1.readline()
                s2 = file2.readline()
                if s1 == s2:
                       newfile.write(s1)
           newfile.close()
```

Or something simpler like @SUTerliakov pointed out
`common_lines = set(file1.readlines()) & set(file2.readlines())`
instead of the checking block such as:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
     with open('file2.txt') as file2:
           newfile = open('newfile.txt','w')
           common_lines = set(file1.readlines()) & set(file2.readlines())
           for line in common_lines:
                 newfile.write(line)

            newfile.close()
```

Comment: `.__eq__` - is it a joke?.. It should be just `==` operator (dunder method is valid, but in general it is discouraged to call such methods directly).

Comment: ...And file remains open. And first code sample is 100% invalid, it a) assumes equal files length and b) gets only empty lines for first file, because `readlines()` exhausted it.

Comment: I can close the file and everything but her got me started thank you

Comment: Glad to be of help :D

Answer (score 3):

I would do like this >>

```
list_of_str_in_file1 = []  # list of strings in file 1
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        list_of_str_in_file1.append(line)

result = []  # list of common strings.
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for line in data:
        if line in list_of_str_in_file1:
            result.append(line)
```

now you can do whatever you need with the resulting list.

(Note to experts: I am a noob, if this is not a good way please comment, so that I can learn.)